# Sizing image in bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap columns with `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4`. Both contain image of same height. When I try to reduce the width of browser the second image is becoming shorter compare to first. I want both in same height. Code is shown below. Thanks in advance.

```css
.offer-row .col-xs-8{padding-right: 8px;}
.offer-row .col-xs-4{padding-left:7px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row offer-row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">

    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/825x500" class="img img-responsive">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/410x500" class="img img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding the following css

```css
.row-eq-height {display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;}.offer-row .col-sm-4{padding-left:7px;overflow-y: hidden;}
.offer-row .col-sm-4 img{min-height:100%; }
.offer-row .col-xs-8{padding-right: 8px;}
.offer-row .col-xs-4{padding-left:7px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
<div class="row offer-row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-xs-8">

    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/825x500" class="img img-fix">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/410x500" class="img img-fix">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The size will reduce, as the screen size reduces, for preventing that you have to write media-query and make your web page responsive.For example in how to write media query, go through given link.

[How to write media query for maiking reponsive websites](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This will make height fixed.

```css
.img-fix{
max-width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
<div class="row offer-row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">

    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/825x500" class="img img-fix">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/410x500" class="img img-fix">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```